# How to change plymouth in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: plymouth

I installed ubuntu 13.10 and I want to change the plymouth.

I tried using these commands but it did not work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mefrio-g/plymouthmanager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plymouth-manager
```

Please help me to solve this problem I want to add my own custom boot screen.

Answer (score 1):

The PPA you are using is outdated. If you want to use this outdated Oneiric version, use

```
sudo sed -i s/saucy/oneiric/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mefrio-g-plymouthmanager-saucy.list 
sudo rename s/saucy/oneiric/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mefrio-g-plymouthmanager-saucy.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plymouth-manager
```

Note that it may be unstable on Saucy.